# Image of argument under Log z.

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Let $z$ be any complex number.
Let $D =\{z: \Re(z) > |\Im(z)|\}$ . Let $f_n(z) = \operatorname{Log} z^n$ where $n = 1,2,3,4$. Then what is $f(D)$

My attempt : I found that $D = \left\{z : \operatorname{Arg}(z) < \frac{\pi}{4}\right\}$ . I wants the solution of the form $f_n (D) = \left\{z : |\Im (z)| < \frac{n\pi}{4}\right\}$ but I don't know how to connect $D = \{z :\operatorname{Arg}(z)<\frac{\pi}{4}\}$ with required result. Please help me.

Comment: Hint: think about the image of a circle (centered at $0$) on $\mathbb{C}$ under logarithm as well as the image of a radical line of that circle under logarithm.

Comment: Image of circle under Logarithm is vertical line and image of radical line under Logarithm is horizontal line. How connect the above information with the given problem?

Comment: @Balijeet So what is the "range" of the radical line you have? $\left(\operatorname{Arg}(z)<\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ and what is $\operatorname{Arg}(z^n)$ in terms of $n$ and $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$?

Comment: $0$ to $(infinity)$

Comment: No, I meant if the radical lines you CANNOT have are bounded by the infinitely long circular sector of central angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$, the image of the radical lines you can have must be horizontal lines ABOVE $z=x+i\frac{\pi}{4}$ since $\operatorname{Log}\left(re^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)=\log |r|+\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: I got above information.
 But I have a little knowledge about it. Please answer my asked problem in proper explanation.

Comment: the answer was proposed. I am glad to help you if you have any further questions.

Comment: I got new information by your hints. It increased my knowledge. I got the main concept. At this time , I'm thinking that this problem is very simple and conceptual. Thank you very much my brother.

Comment: @Balijeet You could accept my answer if you would like to ;) I am very glad that my answer actually helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper explanation you requested.

So first, we want $\Re(z)>|\Im(z)|$.The set of $z$ should be $\{z:|\operatorname{Arg}(z)|<\frac{\pi}{4}\}$. Now let $z=re^{i\theta}$, $r\in\mathbb{R}$, $|\theta|<\frac{\pi}{4}$. We then have
$$\operatorname{Log}(z)=\ln(r)+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$$
Remember that $r\in\mathbb{R}$ can take any value, so the image of the function $f_1$ is the set:
$$f_1(D)=\left\{x+iy:x\in\mathbb{R}, |y|<\frac{\pi}{4}\right\}$$
Finally, if we consider the cases where $n=2,3,4$, the only thing changes is the value of $|\operatorname{Arg}(z^n)|=n|\operatorname{Arg}(z)|$ ($0<n<5$ so the range of this principal argument works fine).

Therefore, what we got is
$$\operatorname{Log}(z^n)=\ln(r^n)+in\operatorname{Arg}(z)$$
Because $r>0$, $r^n$ still has the range of the whole $\mathbb{R}$, therefore
$$f_n(D)=\left\{x+iy:x\in\mathbb{R}, |y|<\frac{n\pi}{4}\right\}$$